I'm having an issue with the time crate when installing Rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound BorrowedFormatItem<'>: Fromstd::result::Result<format_item::Item<'_, format_description::parse::Error>> is not satisfied
--> /Users/kelseywu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/time-0.3.29/src/format_description/parse/mod.rs:86:22
|
86 |     .map(|item| item.into())
|                      ^^^^ the trait Fromstd::result::Result<format_item::Item<'_, format_description::parse::Error>> is not implemented for BorrowedFormatItem<'>, which is required by std::result::Result<format_item::Item<'>, format_description::parse::Error>: Into<>
|
= help: the following other types implement trait From:
BorrowedFormatItem<'> implements From<format_description::component::Component>
BorrowedFormatItem<'a> implements From<&'a [BorrowedFormatItem<'>]>
= note: required for std::result::Result<format_item::Item<'>, format_description::parse::Error> to implement Into<BorrowedFormatItem<'>>
Claude is telling me that this is an issue with my time crate but I am confused on how to fix this. Can someone help?
